# Array imploded with comma and used with a SQL 'IN'

Tags: php, sql, arrays, implode

Why is this PDO query not working properly?

```
$colors = $_GET['color'];
$colors = explode(' ', $colors);
$colors = implode(',',$colors);
$items = $con -> prepare("SELECT * FROM item_descr WHERE color_base1 IN (".$colors.")");
$items ->execute();
while($info = $items->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
echo $info['color_base1'];
}
```

Comment: Have you added a var_dump or something to verify that the query string is what you expect?

Comment: What is the data type of color_base1? String or Integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `$colors` or you are subject to a SQL injection attack.  There is a little-known PHP function `array_fill` that is GREAT for this:

```
$colors = explode(' ', $_GET['color']));
$parameters = join(', ', array_fill(0, count($colors), '?');
$items = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM item_descr WHERE color_base1 IN ({$parameters})");
$items ->execute($colors);
while($info = $items->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))  {
    echo $info['color_base1'];
}
```

---

It appears your problem is that your colors weren't wrapped with quotes, but that problem goes away in my code because it uses bound parameters.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape `$colors` items with quotes to fit `IN()` statement if are dealing with strings:

```
SELECT * FROM item_descr WHERE color_base1 IN ('blue', 'yellow', '#FF0000')
```

Probably your `$color` variable is just comma separated - add quotes.

By the way, to inspect your MySQL error use [PDO::errorInfo](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php) after running the query:

```
var_dump($con -> errorInfo());
```

it will show something like:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; [...]
```

so you can fix your query.

Answer (score 0):

If $colors can contain strings, then you should use

```
function quote_value(& $value, $key) { $value = "'$value'"; }

$colors = $_GET['color'];
$colors = explode(' ', $colors);
array_walk($colors, 'quote_value');
$colors = implode(',',$colors);
// the rest of your code
```